# HTML5 canvas :processingJS

Tags: javascript, html, processing.js

i try to do some animation in HTML5 using processingjs , the problem is i try to attach event 
to for example a square at very low level i.e. by capturing X,Y mouse coordinate and compare with the clicked area .

***the question*** is there any way to attach event like we do in JavaScript or other lang ? if not , any other lib. or framework can help ? because i feel this will not work when have many elements on the canvas .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "mouseClicked" function and check "mouseX" and "mouseY" variables inside. If have the square definition somewhere you can do a collision detection there.